# asp.net mvc5 datetime rendering format

Tags: date, datetime, format, render, asp.net-mvc-5

This is the model :

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> PublishDate { get; set; }
```

This is the view :

```
<dt>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PublishDate)
</dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PublishDate)
     </dd>
```

When I am on English version of the page, date renders as 14/08/2017. When I change language to French then date renders as 14.8.2017. Why is it happening?  can anyone help me? No Matter which Language I select I want the date to be rendered the same way as English(14/08/2017).

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PublishDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

This would work on any server that uses the same 12-month calendar.

You could also create a display template.

Comment: No , still the same.